# Elastalert : Alert if match found in specific path

Tags: elastic-stack, elastalert

I have configured elastalert for alerting simple pattern matches.
For one of our CRM services, we have multiple middle-ware components with the same match keywords (error codes : 404, 400, 500 etc)
Is there a way where I can query for a match from a specific path?

```
# rules to post details
es_host: xx.xx.xx.xx
es_port: 9200
es_username: admin
es_password: admin
name: crm_failure
type: any
index: uat-nonprod*
filter:
 - query:
    term:
        source: "E:\CRMLogs\Workflows\Error\01-07-2019\filebeat"
             message :"ERROR 404"
```

Elastalert does not even trace this incident. Even after lots of simulation.

Comment: can you add an example document which you are trying to query?